# lambda function c++ 11

Tags: c++, audio, c++11, fmod

Any idea how to rewrite this lambda function pre c++11?

```
    if (maxVol != 0)
       std::transform(&spec[0], &spec[sampleSize], &spec[0]
                     , [maxVol] (float dB) -> float {   return dB / maxVol; });
```

The code is from http://katyscode.wordpress.com/2013/01/16/cutting-your-teeth-on-fmod-part-4-frequency-analysis-graphic-equalizer-beat-detection-and-bpm-estimation

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Origional code:

```
if (maxVol != 0)
       std::transform(&spec[0], &spec[sampleSize], &spec[0], [maxVol] (float dB) -> float {   return dB / maxVol; });
```

Lambda:

```
[maxVol] (float dB) -> float {   return dB / maxVol; }
```

Replacement for lambda:

```
struct percent_of {
    //that lambda captures maxVol by copy when constructed
    percent_of(float maxVol) : maxVol(maxVol) {} 
    //the lambda takes a "float dB" and returns a float
    float operator()(float dB) const { return dB / maxVol; }
private:
    float maxVol;
};
```

Replacement for full code:

```
if (maxVol != 0)
       std::transform(&spec[0], &spec[sampleSize], &spec[0], percent_of(maxVol));
```

However, this lambda is so simple, that it is now built into the standard library.  Pre-C++11 had these exact same bits in `boost`.

```
if (maxVol != 0) {
    using std::placeholders::_1;
    auto percent_of = std::bind(std::divides<float>(), _1, maxVol);
    std::transform(&spec[0], &spec[sampleSize], &spec[0], percent_of);
}
```

Comment: I get the errors: 'FrequencyAnalysis::DrawScene()::percent_of' does not have any field named 'maxVol' and use of 'auto' variable from containing function. It doesn't recognize the function inside the std::transform either. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The first was caused by a typo in the name of `maxVol`, and the second by forgetting to actually instantiate `divides`.  I've corrected those.  The third error merely stems from the first two, but the code works now, instead of merely being a guideline.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d8b42fa15ad94ba

Comment: sorry i still get the error: 'no matching function for call to 'transform(float*, float *, float *, FrequencyAnalysis::DrawScene()::percent_of)'

Comment: did you `#include <algorithm>`?

Comment: yes i did, i'm a bit stumped. I cant use your second method as that throws up errors due to the version of c++ i'm writing in.

Comment: Can you open the output window and give us the full error text?  I can't imagine what the problem could be

Comment: I have sorted it now, just needed to define the struct within my header file! Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

1. Use bind1st and bind2nd (in C++11 we would just use bind) for a
   predicate which also takes maxVol as one of its inputs
2. Create a function object which can have a member variable for maxVol.
   Overload operator() and pass this in as a predicate.
3. Use boost lambda.